# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client happens on second click

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

When I execute the following code after the page loads initially, I do not get an error, but when I change the value of the drop down `ddlMode` and execute it again, I get the error:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txtXML="<Root...").`

I did SecurityElement.Escape and this fixes it, but it displays escaped XML and I don't want to display it like this.  Here is the relevant code inside a button click event:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Root",
                    new XAttribute("T", "Test"),
                    new XAttribute("S", ddlMode.SelectedValue),
                    new XAttribute("E", Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                    new XAttribute("F", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()),
                    new XElement("HRS",
                        new XElement("HR",
                            new XElement("RP"),
                            new XElement("RSS",
                                new XElement("RS",
                                    new XElement("PN",
                                        new XElement("GV", txtFirstName.Text),
                                        new XElement("SN", txtLastName.Text)))))));


            txtXML.Text = xml.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ddlMode has AutoPostback set to true.
You'd be better off doing

```
txtXML.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(xml.ToString());
```

This will correctly encode things like the right and left angle brackets which it is interpreting as malicious taggery.